# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range

Tags: c#, request.querystring

I Have another Issue with my Code (ARGGGH!) I have a request.querystring that I am calling and i get the following error **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index**

```
public void getAccountRef()
{
    string getAccountRef = (string)Request.QueryString["AccountRef"].ToString();

    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = getAccountRef;
}
```

Any thoughts why? I am trying to parse the account ref which is going to formatted like REDIT1

Cheers

Justin

Comment: This means `SqlDataSource1` doesn't have a select parameter with index `0`

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet that SqlDataSource1 had no parameters set, so your attempt to access the first (item 0) fails as the index must be in the range from 0 to Count-1 (which nothing satisfies in this case). You need to add the parameter.

Also note that:

```
string getAccountRef = (string)Request.QueryString["AccountRef"].ToString()
```

Is doubly redundant. There's no need to cast the result of `.ToString()` to string, as `ToString()` always returns a string.

There's also no need to call it on the result of `Request.Querystring[fieldName]` as that also always returns a string. The following would suffice:

```
string getAccountRef = Request.QueryString["AccountRef"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it! there was not a parameter set in my SQLDataSource!

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="AccountRef" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Thanks guy's